# how to change the icon of default porlet language in liferay 6.2

Tags: liferay-6, portlet, liferay-hook

In Liferay you can setup (portal-)languages which are available to sites.

In control panel for a site, you can choose which of these languages should be available to a user of that site.

I want to change the flag of the default language porlet in liferay 6.2.

Comment: my problemes is when i selcted the frensh langage , the flag of frensh is displaying in reverse red,white,blue not blue,white,frensh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.liferay.com/en_GB/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/43911597) forum, it looks like the only way to change those images is to replace the files manually.

You can find them under `portal-web/docroot/html/themes/_unstyled/images/language` and the icons should be the size of 16x11px.